# How to create generic relationships with inheritance?

Tags: django, django-models

I have structure something like this: A Campaign can contain multiple Action. Every Action should related to a campaign. There is different type of action, such as Email, Web hook etc.. Common point of these actions is "run" method. When I run campaign's run method, the actions related to the campaign should run too.

I think something like this will work for me:

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def run(self, data):
        for action in self.actions.all():
            action.run(data)

class Action(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(
        Campaign,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='actions',
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def run(self, data):
        print(f'The {self.name} action ran.')
        print(f'Data: {data}')


class EmailAction(Action):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    body = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'email_action'

    def run(self, data):
        super(EmailAction, self).run(data)


class WebhookAction(Action):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    body = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'webhook_action'

    def run(self, data):
        super(WebhookAction, self).run(data)
```

What is the best way to achieve this workflow?

**Scenario:**
I will create a campaign. For example, add-to-cart-notification (campaign name).
Then I will create an EmailAction, and will say "You added the product to the cart".
If one day if I need to push this event to an external service, I will create a web hook action.
Maybe I can one more EmailAction: "Here is the products you may interest"

Comment: Does `Campaign` stores only ids? No any other information?

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what your problem is? Except for the fact that it should be 'for action in self.actions.all()' in your Campaign model your code should work

Comment: @funnydman Yes, there is more fields, but I didn't write them because they aren't related to question.

Comment: @Chris My question is: Is this approach the correct way to achieve this scenario? Also corrected the mistake you have pointed, thank you.

Comment: Actually they are related, it would give more information for building a more accurate db structure.

Comment: @funnydman I added some lines, thank you.

Comment: IMHO your approach looks ok

Comment: @UmutÇağdaşCoşkun Why are explicitly declaring `db_table`?